# Why does my table component filter crash the browser tab?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a page with a table which is working quite fine and is very performant as it should be. I'm now trying to implement a filter for it so the users can easily check only what they need. But one weird thing is happening. If I have the filter component commented out, everything works fine. If I include it in the component it should be, the browser becomes extremely slow and even crashes my chrome tab. I was trying to comment out all the code in that component to check where the problem is but I can't figure it out.

My weird component code without the comments:

```
import { Grid, LuxButton } from 'luxclusif-material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FilterComponentStyles } from './FilterComponent.styles';


export default function FilterComponent() {
    const classes = FilterComponentStyles();

    const [status, setStatus] = useState('Supplier');

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.spacing}>
                {/* commented out stuff */}
            </div>
            <div className={`${classes.statusMenu} ${classes.spacing}`}>
                <Grid
                    container
                    direction="row"
                    justify="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    className={classes.heightStatus}>

                    <div className={classes.rightMargin}>
                        <LuxButton
                            variant="contained"
                            luxColor={(status === 'Supplier' ? 'secondary' : 'default')}
                            onClick={() => setStatus('Supplier')}
                            className={classes.transformTextNone}
                            disableElevation>
                            <span className={classes.addButtonText}>Supplier</span>
                        </LuxButton>
                    </div>

                    <div className={classes.rightMargin}>
                        <LuxButton
                            variant="contained"
                            luxColor={(status === 'Active' ? 'secondary' : 'default')}
                            onClick={() => setStatus('Active')}
                            className={classes.transformTextNone}
                            disableElevation>
                            <span className={classes.addButtonText}>Active</span>
                        </LuxButton>
                    </div>

                    <div className={classes.rightMargin}>
                        <LuxButton
                            variant="contained"
                            luxColor={(status === 'Inactive' ? 'secondary' : 'default')}
                            onClick={() => setStatus('Inactive')}
                            className={classes.transformTextNone}
                            disableElevation>
                            <span className={classes.addButtonText}>Inactive</span>
                        </LuxButton>
                    </div>

                </Grid>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

This `FilterComponent` is being called like this:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} >
    <FilterComponent ></FilterComponent>
    <Table>
        {/* table code */}
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Notes: LuxButton is an extension of material-ui Button and its luxColor property is the extension to the color property.

Comment: could you please add error here as well which is shown in browser console.

Comment: There's no error. I forgot to mention the browser becomes extremely slow in that tab but I edit the post now.

Comment: Show us how you're implementing this component. Is it being called many times?

Comment: No. Only once per page. As simple as this: `<FilterComponent />`

Comment: I updated the post text to reflect this.